# Ruby query Error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.1

i have a user model and a location model . I want to point all the users to the first ocurrence of their location in the location table as shown

```
User
user_id   name  location_id
1         tim     1
2         adam    2
3         Joy     3

Location
location_id  name
1            NewYork
2            NewYork
3            NewYork
```

> Expected Ouput:

```
User
user_id   name  location_id
1         tim     1
2         adam    1
3         Joy     1
```

I tried to run this query but it isnt working:

```
User.joins(:location).update_all("location_id =(select id from locations as l2 where l2.name = locations.name limit 1)")
```

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "locations"
LINE 1: ... =(select id from locations as l2 where l2.name = locations....
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "l2".
```

Any solution?

Comment: locations does not exist for this context. locations.name wont work. Try this: User.joins(:location).update_all("location_id =(select id from locations as l2 where l2.name = (select name from locations l3 where l3.id = users.location_id limit 1)  limit 1)")

Comment: maybe the users will break though... and then you will have to put one more query :(   But I think you should also look for a solution trying to Alias the tables in the active record way...  and then alias Users and Locations from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would expect it to work in SQL;

```
SELECT
a.user_id
,a.name
,fst.ID AS location_ID
FROM locations a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, MIN(location_id) ID FROM locations GROUP BY name) fst
ON a.name = fst.name
```